# Meaning of celibacy in reference to Garuda Puran

Tags: vishnu, krishna, garuda-purana, celibacy

> Having undertaken the incarnation of Koumara and lived in the celestial region the first deity Hari,
> 0 Brahman, practised the most difficult vow of celibacy without any break

Narayana or Hari who was married to Lakshmi Devi is said to have practiced Celibacy? What does Celibacy mean concerning Garuda Puran?

*Note:- Celibacy also means abstaining from marriage*

The Garuda Puran I am reading - https://www.forgottenbooks.com/en/download/TheGarudaPuranam_10521218.pdf

It is given in chapter 1 as Suta preaching The Garuda Puran to other sages who ask about The Supreme Personality Of Godhead

Comment: Celibacy not just means refraining from marriage. Celibacy has to be maintained even in grihasthashram. For example, a grihastha must never think of anyone except his wife, the ratikriya must be done only with the 
 intention of begetting children. And many more such astringent rules apply. Probably you can read more on celibacy and the rules applying for the same here on HSE, by searching it in the, search toolbar.

Comment: Oh...It would be great if this was posted as an answer!

Comment: Hello KrishnaBhakti, from where did you get the quote? If possible, add the source link.

Comment: Yeah Sure I will add it

Answer (score 2):

Scriptures give 2 definitions of Brahmacharya for ordinary Jivas. I don't know whether these definitions apply to Narayana and Lakshmi Devi.

**Brahmacharya (celibacy) for monks**

> Not indulging in sexual intercourse, mentally, verbally or physically
> is the vow of celibacy, with reference to the ascetics and the
> religious students.

**Linga Purana I.8.16**

**Brahmacharya (celibacy) for householders**

> In their case, as prescribed, indulgence in sexual intercourse with
> their wives and abstention from it with other women mentally,
> physically and verbally should be understood as brahmacharya.

**Linga Purana I.8.18**